# Is the functor of PA forms known to be equivalent to the functor of PL forms for noncompact spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rational-homotopy-theory

In the following paper:

*Robert Hardt, Pascal Lambrechts, Victor Turchin, and Ismar Volić*, [**Real homotopy theory of semi-algebraic sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/agt.2011.11.2477), *Algebr. Geom. Topol.* **11** (2011), no. 5, 2477–2545.

the authors construct a functor $\Omega^*_{PA}$ from the category of of semi-algebraic sets to the category of CDGAs, and prove that it is equivalent to the usual functor $A_{PL}(-;\mathbb{R})$ from rational (well, real here) homotopy theory, when restricted to *compact* semi-algebraic sets.

In Section 9.1, they explain that Kontsevich and Soibelmann, in a previous paper, suggested that this equivalence was true for any semi-algebraic set (and even for a bigger class of PA spaces), though the proof of Hardt–Lambrechts–Turchin–Volić does not work for noncompact sets. Has there been any progress on this conjecture? I could not find anything in the literature.